# C++ console program (often) doesn't work, process returned 255 (0xFF)

Tags: c++, console, console-application

I made simple 2D world generator, with some trees. Unfortunately, it not always work. There         is code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a[64][16];
    int lvl=10, num;

    srand(time(NULL));

for (;;)
{
    lvl=10;

    //! system("cls");
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
        {
            a[j][i] = " ";
        }
    }


    for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
    {
        num = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << num;

        if (num == 1)
        {
            if (lvl > 7)
            {
                lvl--;
            }
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            if (lvl < 15)
            {
                lvl++;
            }
        }
        a[j][lvl] = "O";

        num = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (num == 7)
        {
            assert( lvl >= 6 );
            a[j][lvl-6] = "^";
            a[j-1][lvl-5] = "/";
            a[j+1][lvl-5] = "\\";
            a[j][lvl-5] = "|";
            a[j-1][lvl-4] = "/";
            a[j+1][lvl-4] = "\\";
            a[j][lvl-4] = "|";
            a[j-1][lvl-3] = "/";
            a[j+1][lvl-3] = "\\";
            a[j][lvl-3] = "|";
            a[j][lvl-2] = "|";
            a[j][lvl-1] = "|";

        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << " +------------------------------------------------------------    ----+" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        cout << " |";
        for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
        {
            cout << a[j][i];
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << " +----------------------------------------------------------------+"     << endl;
    //! getch();
}
return 0;
```

}
Sometimes it works, sometimes just return 255 (0xFF), and sometimes returns random code (I think) and, I don't know why it happens.

Debuger info:

```
Starting debugger:
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 6.8
Child process PID: 6244
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In std::string::assign () ()
At E:\C++\worldGenerator\main.cpp:59
```

Comment: Please specify how you check the return code. As far as I can see there's nothing in this program that could return anything but 0 without a very visible crash.

Comment: Posting the output of your program would be very helpful to debug it. You say it returns some random code. What is it? Can you post it?

Comment: Sometimes "Process returned 255 (0xFF)", and sometimes "Process returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005)"

Comment: The process is being terminated by the OS because it is generating an exception.  What does your debugger say?  That will locate the point at which the fault occurs and inspection of the variables will probably tell you why - bounds overflow seems likely. I am not at a machine with tools installed at present, but on http://www.compileonline.com/ with the Windows specifics removed it seg-faults.

Comment: I add debuger output.

Comment: Ah... unlucky you are stuck with GDB ;-).  I am sure it is capable of assisting you in this, but not easy to use, and I hardly ever use it (not for years) so I cannot tell you.  The first thing I would do is remove the time call from `srand()` and set it to zero so that it does  *the same thing* every time you run it.

Comment: At least a[j+1][...] indexes the array out-of-bounds.  This UB can have many side-effects, an access violation (0xc0000005) is certainly possible.

Comment: @HansPassant : and `a[j-1], but you should refrain from using the comments for answers on SO - that *is* an answer.

Comment: I just changed "if (num == 7)" to "if (num == 7 && j>2 && j<30)". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VC++ 2013 (after adding the missing  header), the debugger raises an exception in std::string::assign() ans you had found in GDB.  Rolling back up the call stack shows that this occurs at this line:

```
             a[j - 1][lvl - 5] = "/";
```

Line 60 in my modified code with  included.  At this point `j == 0`, so there's your problem right there - indexing `a[-1]`.

By setting srand(0) to make the test repeatable, it fails elsewhere:

```
             a[j + 1][lvl - 4] = "\\";
```

When `j == 64`.  Your problem is that the loop iterates j from 0 to 63, so `j-1` and `j+1` can be out of bounds and should not be used to index `a[]`.

```
    for( int j = 1; j < 63; j++ )
```

allows it to run at least - but may or may not do what you intended.

Comment: It's interesting that my approach of *staring at it* yielded the same answer with much less work. I think the head is the best debugger for this kind of trivial size code. It's certainly fastest. ;-)

Comment: What you should take from this is that learning to use a debugger effectively is a much more efficient debug method than posting to SO!  In GDB you would have needed to display or roll-back the call stack to determine where in your code the failure occurrence and inspect the variable state at that point.  This was trivial in VC++ which has an excellent debugger.  An IDE wrapper for GDB such as that provided by Eclipse or Code::Blocks for example may help encourage you to use its power more regularly.

Comment: Summing up, mainly for the OP: (1) stare at it, or rather, *think!*, and do check documentation of functions used and so on if necessary, and if that doesn't help, (2) use a preferably good debugger, intelligently, and only then, as a last resort, (3) post the question to SO.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : It migh have been hard work in GDB perhaps ;-).  For a trivial problem, perhaps that can be done, but my intent was to "teach to fish" not "feed a fish", and more generally and certainly for large projects and complex problems the debugger is an effective tool - more effective that posting debug questions on SO.

Comment: We seem to be in violent agreement ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : Also sometimes when *code staring*, you cannot *see the wood for the trees* - ha!  Sorry, but I had to. ;-)  But more seriously, while a second pair of eyes can often spot the obvious, the person who wrote the code will often be blind to it.  Almost by definition they already think they wrote the code correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to check your program:

- Added include of `<assert.h>`.
- Commented out the clear screen and wait for keypress, to make it non-interactive.
- Added `assert` statement about the expected value of `lvl`.

Then, yes, it crashed. So the value is ungood. You may now go forth and **debug** your logic.

---

Oh, I couldn't help but debug it a little by the well known method of *staring at it*.

Because I couldn't see any ordinary way that `lvl` could become 6 or less, all updates protected by conditionals.

But as it happens you are indexing your array with `j-1` when `j` can be 0. That would write to some unintended part of memory.

Many C++ implementations have ways of checking the indexing. If not then you can always use `std::vector` and its `at` member function. It provides guaranteed range checking.

Anyway that's what I recommed, create a proper *matrix class* based on a single `std::vector` as storage, and use its `at` method.

---

Instrumented code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a[64][16];
    int lvl=10, num;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (;;)
    {
        lvl=10;

        //! system("cls");
        for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
            {
                a[j][i] = " ";
            }
        }


        for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
        {
            num = rand() % 10 + 1;
            cout << num;

            if (num == 1)
            {
                if (lvl > 7)
                {
                    lvl--;
                }
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                if (lvl < 15)
                {
                    lvl++;
                }
            }
            a[j][lvl] = "O";

            num = rand() % 20 + 1;

            if (num == 7)
            {
                assert( lvl >= 6 );
                a[j][lvl-6] = "^";
                a[j-1][lvl-5] = "/";
                a[j+1][lvl-5] = "\\";
                a[j][lvl-5] = "|";
                a[j-1][lvl-4] = "/";
                a[j+1][lvl-4] = "\\";
                a[j][lvl-4] = "|";
                a[j-1][lvl-3] = "/";
                a[j+1][lvl-3] = "\\";
                a[j][lvl-3] = "|";
                a[j][lvl-2] = "|";
                a[j][lvl-1] = "|";

            }
        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << endl << " +------------------------------------------------------------    ----+" << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            cout << " |";
            for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
            {
                cout << a[j][i];
            }
            cout << "|" << endl;
        }
        cout << " +----------------------------------------------------------------+"     << endl;
        //! getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but I got it. `string a[64][16];` is too small because later you do this:

`a[j+1][lvl-5] = "\\";` with j going up to 64, so I changed it to : `string a[65][16];`.

I also found that if you generate a tree at level 9, 10, or 11 the program also crashes so I added a limit to level in tree generation.

Here is fixed code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a[65][16];
    int lvl=10, num;

    srand(time(NULL));

for (;;)
{
    lvl=10;

    system("cls");
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
        {
            a[j][i] = " ";
        }
    }


    for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
    {
        num = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << num;

        if (num == 1)
        {
            if (lvl > 7)
            {
                lvl--;
            }
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            if (lvl < 15)
            {
                lvl++;
            }
        }
        a[j][lvl] = "O";

        num = rand() % 20 + 1;

        if (num == 7 && (lvl < 9 || lvl > 11))
        {
            assert( lvl >= 6 );
            a[j][lvl-6] = "^";
            a[j-1][lvl-5] = "/";
            a[j+1][lvl-5] = "\\";
            a[j][lvl-5] = "|";
            a[j-1][lvl-4] = "/";
            a[j+1][lvl-4] = "\\";
            a[j][lvl-4] = "|";
            a[j-1][lvl-3] = "/";
            a[j+1][lvl-3] = "\\";
            a[j][lvl-3] = "|";
            a[j][lvl-2] = "|";
            a[j][lvl-1] = "|";

        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl << " +----------------------------------------------------------------+" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        cout << " |";
        for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
        {
            cout << a[j][i];
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << " +----------------------------------------------------------------+"     << endl;
    getch();
}
return 0;
}
```